# Software center shows “use this source” instead of “install”

Tags: 13.10, software-center, package-management

I was downloading vlc media player. Suddenly there was a network problem and it stopped. Then when I tried to install it again it does not show the install option, but instead shows "use this source".

Comment: try to install vlc via terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Install VLC this way.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

Or

Just click [**VLC** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/)

Answer (score 0):

To install VLC using the Software Center with your situation, you need to

1. Click *Use this source* on the VLC page.
2. Wait for some operations to complete.
3. Click the *Install* button on the VLC page (it should re-appear).